# How to get App data from Graph API when user has access to the app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to know how i can access to my app data (title and description) when the user has access to it and get the localized values using the user locale.

My code is this:

```
    var imageUrl = "http://mysite.test/webroot/img/test_image.jpg",
        userID = response.authResponse.userID,
        userLanguage,
        appTitle,
        appDescription;

    if (response.status === 'connected') {

        FB.api(
            "/" + userID,
            function (response) {
                if (response && !response.error) {
                    userLanguage = response.locale;
                }
            }
        );

        FB.api(
            'me/{namespace}:{action}', 'post', 
            {
                object: {
                    "url": imageUrl,
                    "title": appTitle,
                    "description": appDescription,
                    "image": imageUrl
                }
            },
            function(response) {

            }
        );

    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {

        FB.login( function( response ) {
        }, {scope: "publish_actions"} );

    } else {

        FB.login( function( response ) {
        }, {scope: "public_profile"} );
    }
```

I tried to use this code, but the `/me` node returns the user data and i want to get the app data:

```
FB.api(
    "/me",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
      }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the User's locale with

```
/me?fields=id,locale
```

Then you can use this `locale` in the second call for the app:

```
/{app_id}?fields=id,name,description&locale={locale}
```

should work. You need to know the app id and replace `{app_id}` with it. The `locale` parameter defines the locale for which you want to receive the data in.

Please be aware that it's not necessarily content in every locale available...

The list of locales can be found at https://www.facebook.com/translations/FacebookLocales.xml

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.3#readmodifiers

Comment: I'm having a problem and now i don't get the values for the selected locale, i'm trying with the Facebook Debugger and if i set locale to fr_FR it gives me the name and description in Spanish (my default language). I set the values for fr_FR on Localize section